# mount any component in vue 3 and laravel-9

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i´m trying to mount any component with vue 3, this component it´s a datatables with vue-good-table-next. For fill this tables i´m using axios. but only i can mount one table.

this it´s my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import { createApp } from "vue";
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table-next';
import 'vue-good-table-next/dist/vue-good-table-next.css'
import datatablePhysios from "./components/datatablePhysios.vue";
import datatableTreatment from "./components/datatableTreatment.vue";

const app = createApp(datatableTreatment) // here it´s the component

app.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
app.mount("#app")
```

i know that in `createApp()`  i have only one component. But also i´m trying this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from "vue";
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table-next';
import 'vue-good-table-next/dist/vue-good-table-next.css'
import datatablePhysios from "./components/datatablePhysios.vue";
import datatableTreatment from "./components/datatableTreatment.vue";

const app = createApp({}) // here it´s the component

app.component('datatable-physios', datatablePhysios)
app.component('datatable-treatment', datatableTreatment);

app.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
app.mount("#app")
```

with same result. I don´t know how i can to mount more than one component.

**UPDATE (bootstrap.js)**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     forceTLS: true
// });
```

Thanks for read me and sorry for my bad english

Comment: The second one should be working but you also need to add the VueGoodTable as component `import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table-next';` `app.component('VueGoodTable', VueGoodTable)`

Comment: @andredewaard thanks for your response. My problem now it´s that browser console, return this: [Vue warn]: There is already an app instance mounted on the host container.
 If you want to mount another app on the same host container, you need to unmount the previous app by calling

Comment: What is inside your `./bootstrap` file? I think you already create an app instance there. Could you otherwise make a reproduction on codesandbox or jsfiddle?

Comment: @andredewaard i updated my question. I can´t create jsfiddle because i´m doing things with laravel and vue-good-table-next it´s a library. I can´t show my data in data table. Only in webrowser console i have this warning, in network tab i have my data, but my table it´s not filled